# Unable to export data to excel in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, nativescript

I am working with react native, and I want to export data to excel. I have tried react-data-export package and installed react-native-fs and also linked packages. I got build success, but after running project it shows error like,

"error: Error: Unable to resolve module fs from node_modules\tempa-xlsx\xlsx.js: fs could not be found within the project.error: Error: Unable to resolve module fs from node_modules\tempa-xlsx\xlsx.js: fs could not be found within the project."

Could you please support me to resolve this issue. I am new in react native.